# Is it ok to store mdf files on different drives (and ldf files)?

Tags: sql-server

The maximum space per drive is limited and I have a lot of databases.  Would it be ok to store the dbs on different drives like this?

```
C: SQL Server install
E: MDF1
F: MDF2
G: MDF3
H: LDF1
I: LDF2
J: LDF3
```

---

Environment = one instance of SQL Server 2016 Standard

---

Edit: I know that it is recommended that mdf and ldf files be stored on separate drives, but I just wasn't sure how far this concept could be stretched :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes!  As a matter of fact you can significantly increase performance by doing so.   If the drives are physical moving your LDF (log) and MDF (data) files to different drives the resource load is spread around.  I've personally had many more MDF and LDF files split out than you have in your example, it's great.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/410be90a-52da-439a-8826-20932ec1481b/separate-drives-for-tempdb-ldf-mdf-?forum=sqlgetstarted

And if you can monitor the drives it will help you fine tune which db is under the most actual load (although you can see some of this with Dynamic Management Views in MSSQL too)

There is also a school of thought of placing the tempdb on its own drive and having a file for each physical core the server has.  And if you could put each on it's own drive, even better (although unrealistic due to cost)
https://logicalread.com/sql-server-tempdb-best-practices-placement-w01/

This can help greatly with reducing disk contention and thus deadlocks.  Lots of reasons to do this, and if you have access to solid state (or other very fast drives like a fiber SAN), even better.  For a well designed database disk access is usually the hardest bottleneck to overcome.

A big key is the drives should be physically separate, simply making a partition isn't going to gain you much.  Searching around for best practices will lead you to trying to have lots of fast storage for SQL and leveraging that as best as possible, lots of science to it but a lot of art too :)